# Show Verify Your Email Address on login attempt in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to show "Verify Your Email Address" error message on login.

Normally after login if we access some routes we can show this message but don't want the user login if email is not verified.

I tried "Verified" middleware on login post route but its not working. is there any laravel way to do this?

Comment: did you use `'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class`?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.8 you can add

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

to your routes file, this will send users to the verify email page if they are not verified. Users are not able to go anywhere else when logged in until they are verified.

Don't forget that the pages for verification are created with the artisan command

```
php artisan make:auth
```